# #1064-error in sql syntax

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-error-1064

I have been trying to validate a user through his username and password through a mySql procedure

```
    delimiter //
    create function validate_user(username_1,password_1)
    return char(1)
    DETERMINISTIC
    begin
    declare ret char(1);
    if exists(select * from logintable where userid=username_1 and password=password_1) then
       set ret='1';
    endif;
    return (ret);
    end;//
    delimiter ;
```

But i've been getting error #1064 error in sql syntax.

Comment: Does the error indicate *where* the syntax problem is?

Comment: It's saying line no 1..

Answer (score 0):

line no 3 in your code

```
return char(1)
```

should be

```
returns char(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things;

- You're not declaring a type for your parameters.
- RETURN should be RETURNS in the function declaration
- ENDIF should be END IF

In other words;

```
create function validate_user(username_1 VARCHAR(32), password_1 VARCHAR(32))
returns char(1)
DETERMINISTIC
begin
declare ret char(1);
if exists(select * from logintable where userid=username_1 and password=password_1) then
   set ret='1';
end if;
return (ret);
end;//
```

[An SQLfiddle with all corrections](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6198b).

Comment: Thanks and one more doubt.. I have created a trigger where I've used endif and it works perfectly fine..can u explain me the difference..

Comment: @SudhirSomasundaram Sorry, no, I can't think of a place where ENDIF would work. ELSEIF is the closest I know of.

Comment: sorry my fault..I did not notice properly..and what is return keyword used for??

Comment: @SudhirSomasundaram `RETURNS` says what the return type of the function is, and `RETURN` sets the return value of the entire function. For example, you may want to use `RETURNS INT` to say that the return value of the function is an integer and `RETURN 5` to make the entire function return 5.